# calculating percentage in postgresql with conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

**I have one table and I want to calculate the percentage of one column**
I tried to do so in two ways. 
but I am actually face with error.

The error is 'syntax error at or near "select"'

This is my code in below:

```
WITH total AS 
(
    select krs_name,count(fclass) as cluster
    FROM residentioal
    GROUP BY krs_name
)
SELECT total.cluster, 
       total.krs_name
       (select count(fclass)
        FROM   residentioal
        where  fclass='village' 
        or     fclass='hamlet' 
        or     fclass='suburb' 
        or     fclass='island'
        AND    krs_name = total.krs_name
       )::float / count(fclass) * 100 as percentageofonline
 FROM  residentioal, total 
 WHERE residentioal.krs_name = total.krs_name
 GROUP BY total.krs_name total.krs_name
```

My table has 5437 rows in which there is 8 group of krs_name and in the other column namely fclass, there is 6 group. Therefore I want to calculate the percentage of 4 groups from fclass for each krs_name . thus, i have to first query the count(fclass) group by krs_name  and then query the count of fclass where fclass is equal to my condition group by krs_name and finally count(fclass) "with condition" / count(fclass) "total fclass" * 100 goup by krs_name?

I'm using Postgresql 9.1.

Comment: Syntax error in there, `SELECT total.cluster, total.krs_name (` - suspect you want a comma after total.krs_name before the parens.

Comment: Some sample data and your expected output would really go a long way here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
SELECT total.cluster, total.krs_name (
```

The open paren makes no sense.

But, this seems to do what you want and it is much simpler:

```
SELECT r.krs_name, COUNT(*) as total,
       AVG( (fclass in ('village', 'hamlet', 'suburb', 'island'))::int ) * 100 as percentageofonline
FROM residentioal r 
GROUP BY r.krs_name
```

Comment: Many Thanks  dear Linoff

That was the precise solution which i was looking for.